# How is localScale reducing in this Fractal code sample for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fractals

I am following this Unity Fractal example:

http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/constructing-a-fractal/

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Fractal : MonoBehaviour {

    public Mesh mesh;
    public Material material;
    public int maxDepth = 20;
    public int depth = 0;
    public float childScale = 0.5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material;
        if(depth < maxDepth)
        {
            new GameObject("Fractal Child").AddComponent<Fractal>().Initialise(this);

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void Initialise(Fractal parent)
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.transform.localScale);
        mesh = parent.mesh;
        material = parent.material;
        maxDepth = parent.maxDepth;
        childScale = parent.childScale;
        Debug.Log("childScale = " + childScale);
        depth = parent.depth + 1;
        transform.parent = parent.transform;
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one * childScale;
        Debug.Log("localScale = " + transform.localScale);
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.up * (0.5f + 0.5f * childScale);
    }
}
```

Up to this point I do have a vertical stack of boxes on top of each other, where each box is half the size of the box below it (childScale is set to 0.5f).

What I don't quite get is why each gameobject (Fractal instance) is half the size of its parent.  childScale is always 0.5f, I dont see how it would reduce to 0.25f, 0.125f etc in this code to make each instance which is recursively created - half the size of it's parent.

Any advice appreciated.

Image below is result (note that this is using a childScale of 0.9f not 0.5f).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale shown in the editor is local scale. Local scale is relative to the transforms parent. The fractal example is nested. So if your top level parent is .5 local scale, it's also .5 world scale since it has no parent. Your next object down is .5 local scale, but (.5 * .5) world scale. Next object down is .5 local scale, (.5 * .5 * .5) world scale. See where this rabbit hole is going? :)

Comment: Hi, so it is only the line which assigns the transform.parent which actually causes the reduction in scale? i.e by making it a child of another object, local scale kicks in.

Comment: Let me put it this way.
World scale = Local scale * world scale of parent.

When unity does the above calculation, it starts at the top and works down. World scale is called "lossy scale" by the way.

Setting the parent is not what causes the reduction in scale, telling the object that it is half the size of it's parent does.

Comment: So what happens if I suddenly reparent to another game object with a different scale?  The act of reparenting wont make it re-evaluate it's local scale again relative to its new parent?

Comment: That depends on what is passed as the second parameter (or using the default by not passing the second parameter at all).
[Transfom.SetParent(Transform parent, bool worldPositionStays);](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

Comment: Thanks, although I am not calling setParent method, I am only doing this: transform.parent = parent.transform;

Comment: As far as I know, that is the same result as SetParent(parent, false).
Which is exactly how your example is working out...

Comment: there has to be a difference between a parameterised method call, and a straight assignment?

Comment: Only if the parameters cause the method to do something other than the straight assignment. Try it yourself.

Comment: Perhaps the scale is worked out each frame based on the parent and scaled accordingly.  The method call I understand, in that method call is the code to resize based on the new parent...at the time of assignment.  But changing a reference won't do anything on its own?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. When the world scale is calculated, it uses localscale and the hierarchy. A good way to visualize what happens is to put two objects in a scene. Put both at .5 localscale. They look the same size. Drag one onto the other, this is the equivalent of SetParent(parent, true). Now check the scale of the child. You will see the number changed to 1 localscale. 
Change it back to .5 localscale, and you will see the child become half the size of the parent. This is what the result of SetParent(parent, false) or transform.parent = parent would be.

Comment: No problem. I understand wanting to know how the nuts and bolts work, instead of "just trust the magic". :)